# preg_match and long strings

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

This is the preg_match i am trying to use to find specific text in text file.

```
if (preg_match($regexp,$textFile,$result) > 0) {
    echo "Found ".$result[0];
} else {
    echo "Not found";
}
```

However, the result is always `Found` and nothing more. The result array is empty. Now i read that preg_match can't work with long strings.

My text file is about 300KB so thats 300000 characters i guess.

I am 100% sure that the searched string is in the text file, and the fact that preg_match function returns value above 0 means it found it, but it didn't place it into the result array somehow.

So my question would be, how do i make it work?

regexp would be `/[specific text]\{(\d*)\}/` so, of course i want to be able to get the number in the parentheses.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll be glad I found this question. As of PHP 5.2, they introduced a limit on the size of text that the PCRE functions can be used on, which defaults to 100k. That's not so bad. The bad part is that it **silently fails** if greater than that.

The solution? Up the limit. The initialization parameter is `pcre.backtrack_limit`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for reply, but i think i am doing something wrong. I use wampServer, i have gone to php.ini file and changed the pcre setting to 1 million, restarted all services, but i still get the same result :( Just plain word "Found " and nothing more.

Comment: @aleluja In your script (at the top) add `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_STRICT);` and try it again. Also, you may want to post your actual script to see if it can be reproduced.

Comment: I did something very silly. It does work. As you can see, in my regexp i used "[" and "]" characters, and i totally forgot they are special, i forgot to escape them, because these 2 characters were a part of a text i search for. I escaped them and now i get the result i was expecting for. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Don't follow @cletus answer, that is dangerous. It is about the stack size managed by the OS itself. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7627962/1077650

Answer (score 1):

No, don't up the `pcre` limit. Don't do things without understand them. This is a common bug with php pcre

Read this awesome answer by @ridgerunner :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7627962/1077650

> this class of regex will repeatably (and silently) crash Apache/PHP with an unhandled segmentation fault due to a stack overflow!
>
> PHP Bug 1: PHP sets: `pcre.recursion_limit` too large.
>
> PHP Bug 2: `preg_match()` does not return FALSE on error.