# PHP preg_match_all 100 MB file

Tags: php, regex, file

I have read that "preg_match_all" is not made for parsing large files, but I need to do that. I have increased:

```
pcre.backtrack_limit=1000000000
pcre.recursion_limit=1000000000
```

my PHP memory_limit is set to 5000M and script still ends without any error or exception within 0,2 sec...

Is the only solutinon split the 100M file into 100 small 1M files?

Thanks for help

Comment: What's your code? It should work fine on large files, but it'll be a huge memory hog. A hugeeee one.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/3041137 its ugly.. I know... FOR, FOR, FOR ...

Comment: PS: I have 8GB RAM (5GB free)

Comment: If it's failing really quickly, you probably just have a `parse error`. Turn on PHP error reporting. Also, when sharing your code, you should post it in the question above, and format it nicely.

Comment: Its not parse error... on small chunk of data its working..

Comment: Show us part of your code - how match should look like?

Comment: 72 MB, and code is here: gist.github.com/3041137

Comment: Note that you can't just increase `pcre.recursion_limit` - you also need to increase the stack size of the running executable (i.e. `php.exe` or `httpd.exe` on Win32 machines). See: my related answer to: [RegExp in preg_match function returning browser error](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7627962/433790) which explains why really bad things can happen with PHP/PCRE and "large" target strings, (and how you can avoid them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base on your [code](https://gist.github.com/3041137) I suggest you to do it this way:

1. Set variable `$data` to empty string
2. Set variable `$work` to empty string; read block of data and append this string to `$data`
3. Use regex `#^(.*?)(<tr>\n(?!.*<tr>\n).*)$#` to split `$data` to `$work` and `$data`
4. Find all matches in `$work`
5. Go back to point #2 while data available
6. Find all matches in `$data`

Comment: 2. how big blick of data? What if I read "<tr>data</tr><tr>da"... The second data "da" will be not processed..

Comment: @MarekJavůrek - you can do this with **any size of block** and it will work. Regarding your question of example - it will be split to 2 parts and second will be processed with new block of data (in point #2 it says **append** which means to add to the end of existing one: `$data = $data . $new` or `$data .= $new`) - just code it and test it.

Answer (score 4):

Consider using command line tools which are much better suited to deal with large amounts of data.

grep, sed, awk, or some combination thereof.